# Tokenising word

Tags: c

I'm trying to extract each individual word in a sentence. I think my general logic is on the right track, however, my program isn't printing anything. Can anyone suggest the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define isWordChar(c) (isalnum(c) || (c) == '\'' || (c) == '-')

int main(){
  char *lower_line = "Oh dear! Oh dear! I'm late!";
  char *word;
  for (int k = 0; k != '\0'; k++){
     for (int j = 0; j != ' '; j++){
          if (isWordChar(lower_line[k]) == 1){
              word[j] = lower_line[k];
              k++; j++;
          } else if (isWordChar(lower_line[k]) == 0){
              k++;
          } else if (lower_line[k] == ' ') {
              word[j] = '\0';
             printf("%s\n", word);
             break;
          }
       }
   }
}
```

**Expected output**

```
Oh
dear
Oh 
dear
I'm
late
```

Comment: A good compiler should have warned that `word` is being used uninitialized.

Comment: Also, you should be able to do this with just one loop and some state variable that indicates whether or not you are currently within a word.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, you really did not make `word` point to a valid memory before you make use of it. This causes access to invalid memory location which invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

*Lazy* solution: make `word` an array of the same length as that of the input string to be processed.